# In AWS Cloud9, is it possible with instance metadata or the cli to know the user name of the person utilising the session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, command-line-interface, aws-cloud9

Is it possible using the CLI in AWS cloud9 to acquire the current user name?

In terraform its possible to get a user's display name with a module like
`data.aws_canonical_user_id.current.display_name`

...But it would be good to also be able to achieve this without terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to use AWS CLI, that [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/finding-canonical-user-id.html) explain how to get the canonical user id:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query Owner.ID --output text
```

Display Name:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query Owner.DisplayName --output text
```

Account id:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tested this but did not get a user name.  aws s3api list-buckets --query Owner.ID --output text
13bba5d20e85603c4e8282a9786beae03eb32a576183e6bd6514d0a8d8c823b2

Comment: @openCivilisation Oh. Sorry. Answer updated.